# how to plot $x=0$ and $y=0$

Tags: plotting

I tried to plot plane $x = 0$ and $y=0$ with `Plot3D[x = 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]` but it seems that it didn't work out. How can I plot the above planes?

Also is there a way to plot with z parameter being in the function?
Note: I was trying to illustrate a closed surface by planes x=0,y=0,z=0 and 2x+2y+z=4

Comment: You should use the documentation. A question like how to add labels or titles will often be easily answered by selecting the function name (in this case Plot3D) and pressing F1. possible options and their possible arguments are listed in the dropdown titled "More Information" or under the Options dropdown.

Comment: Amm x=0 and y=0 is a line (ie. intersection of two planes). Or did you want to plot two planes.

Comment: I was trying to illustrate a closed surface bound by x=0,y=0,z=0 and 2x+2y+z=4

Comment: @experimentX I think the most convenient way to get what you need is `RegionPlot`, see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Definitons from Planetmath**

We may show that a first-degree equation
\begin{align}
Ax+By+Cz+D = 0
\end{align}
between the variables $x$, $y$, $z$ represents always a plane. In fact, we may without hurting generality suppose that, $D \leqq 0$. Now $R := \sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2} > 0$. Thus the length of the radius vector of the point, $(A,B,C)$, is $R$. Let the angles formed by the radius vector with the positive coordinate axes be $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. Then we can write
$$A = R\cos\alpha, \quad B = R\cos\beta, \quad C = R\cos\gamma$$
(cf. direction cosines). Dividing first degree equation term wise by $R$ gives us
$$x\cos\alpha+y\cos\beta+z\cos\gamma+\frac{D}{R} = 0,$$
where, $\frac{D}{R} \leqq 0$. The last equation represents a plane whose distance from the origin is $-\frac{D}{R}$ and whose normal line forms the angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ with the coordinate axes.

Since the coefficients $A,B,C$ are proportional to the direction cosines of the normal vector of this plane, they are direction numbers of the normal line of the plane.

**Examples**

The equations of the coordinate planes are $x = 0$ ($yz$-plane); $y = 0$ ($zx$-plane), $z = 0$ ($xy$-plane); the equation of the plane through the points, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ is $x+y+z = 1$.

Try this for $z=0$ and $x+y+z=1$.

```
f[x_, y_] = 0;
Plot3D[{f[x, y], x + y - 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None,AxesLabel ->  
Automatic,PlotStyle -> {{Directive[Pink, Opacity[0.6], 
Specularity[White, 40]]}, {Directive[Cyan, Opacity[0.9], 
Specularity[White, 10]]}},BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

[image]

**Your Problem**

Now lets plot the plane $2 x + 2 y + z =4$ that you want with the planes $x=0,y=0$

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@{2 x + 2 y + z == 4, {0, y, 0}, {x, 0, 0}},
{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness@0.003], 
MeshFunctions -> (Total[{0, 0, #3}] &), 
ColorFunction -> 
Function[{x, y, z, f}, Evaluate[Hue[#] & /@ {x, y, z}]], 
AxesLabel -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, 
ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.6], Specularity[White, 30]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

You can also use `RegionPlot` the see the 3D area enclosed by these three planes namely $xy,yz,zx$ that are meshed with white lines.

```
pic = RegionPlot3D[2 x + 2 y + z < 4, {x, -0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 8}, 
BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], Mesh -> None, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.9]], 
ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
Boxed -> False];
Show[pic, ContourPlot3D[
Evaluate@{{x, 0, 0}, {0, y, 0}, {0, 0, z}}, {x, -0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 8},    
BoundaryStyle -> Directive[White, Thick], 
MeshStyle -> Directive[White, Thickness@0.003], 
ColorFunction -> Function[z, RGBColor[z, 1 - z, 1]], 
AxesLabel -> Automatic, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting any labels .. so i don't know which is which

Comment: thank .you ... but still my plane was $x=0, y=0$

Comment: @experimentX check update!

Answer (score 6):

You can plot the two planes using `ParametricPlot3D`.

Here is an example

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{0, u, v}, {u, 0, v}}, {u, -10, 10}, {v, -10, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ImagePadding -> 60]
```

[image: Example image]

The xy plane is coloured red and the yz blue.

Here is the space you wanted to visualize:

```
i = {1, 0, 0}; j = {0, 1, 0}; k = {0, 0, 1};
n = {2, 2, 1}; d = 4;
r = RotationMatrix[{i, n}];
jc = r.j; kc = r.k;

ParametricPlot3D[{{0, u, v}, {u, 0, v}, {u, v, 0}, 
  jc*u + kc*v + d}, {u, -15, 15}, {v, -15, 15}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Directive[Orange, Opacity[.5]]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ImagePadding -> 60]
```

[image: Enclosed space]

This works by first finding two orthogonal unit vectors on the plane (`jc` and `kc`). The vectors are found by using a rotation matrix that rotates the `i` unit vector along the direction of the plane normal vector `n`. If the same rotation matrix is applied to `j` and `k` we get the correct unit vectors on the plane.

Comment: thank very much you too ...  and everyone

Answer (score 5):

Taking into account the edit of the post you need `RegionPlot3D`, e.g.

```
RegionPlot3D[ 2 x + 2 y + z - 4 <= 0, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 4}, 
              PlotStyle -> Directive[Lighter @ Green, Opacity[0.2]], AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

or making it more transparent we reduce slightly mesh lines :

```
RegionPlot3D[ 2 x + 2 y + z - 4 <= 0, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 4}, 
              PlotStyle -> Directive[ Cyan, Opacity[0.1], Specularity[0.9]], 
              AxesLabel -> Automatic, Mesh -> {0, 0, 3} ]
```

[image]

or making use of `ContourPlot3D`, e.g.

```
ContourPlot3D[ 2 x + 2 y + z == 4, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 4}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

[image]

and plotting `x == 0`, `y == 0`, ...

```
ContourPlot3D[{ x == 0, y == 0, z == 0}, {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, {z, 0, 4},  
               MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.35],
               RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 2 x + 2 y + z - 4 <= 0]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Yes, this question is now actually two questions...

Comment: thank you ... i think i'll use this

Comment: @Ajasja Thanks for the upvote, I upvoted your answer too.

Answer (score 3):

> Also is there a way to plot with z parameter being in the function?

If you are asking for a method to plot an arbitrary surface, you can use `ParametricPlot3D` which allows you to specify an arbitrary expression for the {x,y,z} coordinates, and have this span two parameters to form a surface.

ParametricPlot3D[v1 {10,0}+v2{0,1,1}, {v1, -1, 1}, {v2, -1, 1}]