# region plot in a 2-simplex

Tags: plotting, simplex

I want to plot a 2-dimensional region with constraint $x+y\le N$, i.e., I want to plot a sub-region inside a 2-simplex.

As an example:

```
Module[{n = 300, p = 0.5},
RegionPlot[{y > (1/2)*(n - x) && y + x <= n && y > p/(1 - p)*x}, 
{x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[0.5]}]]
```

What should I do to transform the region to a 2-simplex?

**Edit 1 & 2 & 3**

The command above will give you the following plot:

[image]

which clearly satisfies the $x+y\le N$ constraint. So I want a coordinate transform that changes the shape of the yellow area into the shape of the red area in the plot below (it is from Matlab):

[image]

Comment: Is this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7024/how-to-plot-x-0-and-y-0/7029#7029)  helpful?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Your plot already lies in the 2-simplex $x\ge0,y\ge0,x+y\le N$. Are you looking for [a plot that looks like an equilateral triangle](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39733/484)? Please explain what you mean by "transform the region into a 2-simplex".

Comment: @Artes, not really...

Comment: @RahulNarain, it's certainly related, but the OP seemed to want something rather advanced. I have a very difficult time extracting what I need from the post.

Comment: guys, I have reworded the question and hope this time it is clear.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, sorry the value of $p$ should be 0.5. My intent is to see how the shape of the area changes with $p$. Yes, I want a coordinate transform. I have modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
rp = Module[{n = 300, p = 0.5}, 
  RegionPlot[{y > (1/2)*(n - x) && y + x <= n && y > p/(1 - p)*x},
     {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotPoints -> 100,
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.8]], ImageSize -> 300]];
toSimplex = #1 {1, 0} + #2 {1, Sqrt[3]}/2 &;
Panel@Row[{rp, MapAt[toSimplex @@ # &, rp, {{1, 1, ;;}}]}]
```

[image]

```
rp2 = Module[{n = 300, p = 0.5},  RegionPlot[{y > (1/2)*(n - x) && y + x <= n && 
    y > p/(1 - p)*x,  x + y < n}, {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.8]], Directive[White, Opacity[0.1]]},
    PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 300]];
Panel@Row[{rp2, MapAt[toSimplex @@ # &, rp2, {{1, 1, ;;}}]}]
```

Note: In version 9, one can use `Span` objects in the third argument of `MapAt` as first noted in [this answer by Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31173/125).

[image]

You can also use

```
tF = FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]}/2},
     {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}][[2]];
MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, tF] &, rp2, {1}] //Panel
```

[image]

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on the rather uncommon syntax of your `MapAt` call?

Comment: @Sjoerd, thanks. Updated and added a reference to [Kuba's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31173/125) regarding the `MapAt` usage with `Span`s. (`{{}}` in the original was a copy/paste error.)

Comment: It did work, even with the error... +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful:

```
Module[{n=300,p=0.29,r1,r2,r3,r4,x,y},
r1=y>(1/2)*(n-x);
r2=y+x<=n;
r3=y>p/(1-p)*x;
(*RegionPlot[#,{x,0,n},{y,0,n},PlotStyle\[Rule]Opacity[.3]]&/@{r1,r2,r3}*)
Show[RegionPlot[#,{x,0,n},{y,0,n},PlotStyle->Opacity[.3]]&/@{r1,r2,r3}]
]
```

[image: code result]